# Laravel modify array request

Tags: arrays, laravel, post, laravel-8

im new using laravel and i get a problem.
and there is my var_dump (post request)

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▼
#parameters: array:12 [▼
  "_token" => "R1fnZMtNA55fy1plkTuztuhMZ1ExvkSw01GJq4rN"
  "spg" => "test"
  "nama" => "Reynaldo"
  "alamat" => "123"
  "hp" => "2134"
  "ccs" => "1"
  "cos" => "2"
  "oss" => "Qty"
  "tvs" => "Qty"
  "tcs" => "Qty"
  "lngs" => "Qty"
  "tks" => "Qty"
]
```

this if my HTML form:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)

        <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
            <label for="{{ $product->slug }}" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ $product->nama }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <select class="custom-select col-sm-2" name="{{ $product->slug }}" required>
                    <option hidden>Qty</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        @endforeach
```

the problem is, how can I modify post request (add array and don't send 'qty' value)?
i want to look like this :

```
+request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▼
#parameters: array:12 [▼
  "_token" => "R1fnZMtNA55fy1plkTuztuhMZ1ExvkSw01GJq4rN"
  "spg" => "test"
  "nama" => "Reynaldo"
  "alamat" => "123"
  "hp" => "2134"
  product array [
  "ccs" => "1"
  "cos" => "2"
  "oss" => "Qty"
  "tvs" => "Qty"
  "tcs" => "Qty"
  "lngs" => "Qty"
  "tks" => "Qty"
  ]
]
```

very grateful if someone helps. sorry for my broken English.
thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

try this

---

`<select class="custom-select col-sm-2" name="{{ $product->slug }}[]" required>`

---

now your select data come as array formate and its name will be  $product->slug's name

Comment: thanks, and now how can i filter the data (no Qty value send) ?